# CMake custom target name conflicts between subdirectories

Tags: c++, cmake

I am writing a game engine and I have a directory called `thirdparty` where all external libraries my engine uses are placed:

```
thirdparty/...
          /zlib
          /freetype2
          /SDL2
          /...
```

So, the engine directory structure looks like:

```
engine/actors
engine/memory_allocator
engine/renderer
engine/...
engine/thirdparty
engine/thirdparty/CMakeLists.txt
engine/CMakeLists.txt
```

The `engine/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.2)

project(Engine)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -Werror")
# Include build directory to be able to include generated files:
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
file(GLOB GLAD_SOURCES thirdparty/glad/src/glad.c)
file(GLOB ACTOR_SOURCES actors/*.cpp)
file(GLOB LOGIC_SOURCES logic/*.cpp)
file(GLOB UI_SOURCES ui/*.cpp)
set(SOURCES ${GLAD_SOURCES}
            ${ACTOR_SOURCES}
            ${LOGIC_SOURCES}
            ${UI_SOURCES})
add_library(engine SHARED ${SOURCES})

include_directories(thirdparty/glm/)
include_directories(thirdparty/glad/include)
include_directories(thirdparty/tinyxml2/)
include_directories(thirdparty/zlib/)
include_directories(thirdparty/sdl2/SDL2-2.0.5/)
include_directories(./)
add_subdirectory(../../thirdparty thirdparty)

target_link_libraries(engine SDL2)
target_link_libraries(engine tinyxml2)
target_link_libraries(engine zlib)
```

The `engine/thirdparty/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(BUILD_CPU_DEMOS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(BUILD_DEMOS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(BUILD_EXTRAS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(BUILD_BULLET2_DEMOS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(BUILD_UNIT_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(FREETYPE_NO_DIST OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

set(OLD_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "")
# add_subdirectory(bullet3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${OLD_CXX_FLAGS}")
add_subdirectory(freetype2)

set(BUILD_TESTING OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
add_subdirectory(tinyxml2)

add_subdirectory(sdl2/SDL2-2.0.5/)

add_subdirectory(zlib)
```

So, the main engine `CMakeLists.txt` is in the root directory of the engine's sources and there is another `CMakeLists.txt` for building third-party libraries in the `thirdparty` subdirectory of engine's root directory.

The problem is that some of subdirectories in the thirdparty, for example, SDL2 and zlib contain the same target names, added via `add_custom_target` and so CMake fails to generate the `Makefile` because of this naming conflicts:

zlib's CMakeLists.txt (in the end):

```
# uninstall target
if(NOT TARGET uninstall)
  configure_file(
      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake.in"
      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake"
      IMMEDIATE @ONLY)

  add_custom_target(uninstall
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake)
endif()
```

SDL2's CMakeLists.txt:

```
##### Uninstall target #####

configure_file(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake.in"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake"
    IMMEDIATE @ONLY)

add_custom_target(uninstall
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake)
```

So the final error is:

```
CMake Error at /home/user/engine/thirdparty/sdl2/SDL2-2.0.5/CMakeLists.txt:1624 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "uninstall" because another target
  with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom target
  created in source directory
  "/home/user/engine/thirdparty/zlib".  See
  documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
```

Is there any way to fix this? Perhaps, there is a way to rename these targets by adding any prefix to it so they will never conflict?

Comment: Targets have to be unique. However, why not just use a unique name, eg:  `add_custom_target(zlib_uninstall ...)` and `add_custom_target(sdl2_uninstall ...)`?

Comment: @SteveLorimer these are not my projects, I can't change their `CMakeLists.txt`, so the question is about what can I do without modifying their files?

Comment: Don't bundle (use `find_package()` with FindSDL2.cmake and FindZlib.cmake things). Other option is to bundle and use `ExternalProject_Add()`.

Answer (score 2):

It mostly depends on which generators you are targeting. A solution that imposes limitations on them is using [`ALLOW_DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_TARGETS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/ALLOW_DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_TARGETS.html).

As from the documentation:

> Allow duplicate custom targets to be created.

It works only for Makefile generators anyway:

> For projects that care only about Makefile generators and do not wish to support Xcode or VS IDE generators, one may set this property to true to allow duplicate custom targets.

Otherwise consider to not pack dependencies with the project directly and use the other tools around (like `Find*`) to get them along with the right paths on the target systems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have upvoted it. However, it seems to me, the better solution is to use `ExternalProject` module as @Velkan have said.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Yeah, I've used external projects in similar cases indeed. ;-)